# LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment

Tags: beamer, errors

I am new in LaTeX. I am getting an annoying error. "LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment."
please help me how to solve it. I couldn't figure that out. I am attaching a picture for more details. 
used packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
```

[image]
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You have an \item directly after the \begin{frame}.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! We prefer to see plain code instead of images with code.

Comment: As @UlrikeFischer  (and your compiler) said, your error is that there is an `\item` without being inside a `\begin{itemize}` or `\begin{enumerate}` environment and their corresponding `\end`.

Comment: Off-topic, but you don't need `graphicx` or `xcolor` with beamer

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you like to convert your comment into a short answer or should this be closes as "solved in comments"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments